# Handling back navigation in WebBrowser control preserving the previous scroll position

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-7, navigation, webbrowser-control

I know there a lot of questions asking about how to handle the `back` navigation in the `WebBrowser` control in WP7. And a lot of answers too,  to achieve the same, using stacks, `InvokeScript`, etc.., and I am currently using this approach, and it works fine (JavaScript):

```
 private void BackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
        webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {

     }
 }
```

But however say when a user scrolls down to `section 'n'` in a webpage, and a link from there takes him to a new page, and then the `back` button is pressed, the page successfully navigates back to the previous page, but is at the top of the page, i.e., `section '1'`.

I would however like to preserve the user's scroll position in the previous page, and send him back to the previous page and down at the position from where the link took him, so that he doesn't have to scroll down all over again, i.e., if a link at `section 'n'` takes him to `page2` from `page1`, after clicking back, it should take him back to `page1` and scrolled down till `section 'n'`.

Thanks.

(The back button that I'm using is a button on the ApplicationBar and not that of the phone's.)

Note: This is how the back button works in the Internet Explorer browser of the Windows Phone, preserving scroll positions.

Comment: Is the site the user's browsing to your site?

Comment: Nope. But I'm guessing the solution mostly has to be with JavaScript. So in that case, it may not matter much whether I write the site's code, as long as I'm able to execute JS using `InvokeScript` from C#. Any solutions if I own the site?

Comment: If you'd own the site, I'd say saving the scroll position in JS somehow when clicking on the first link, then when coming back, check if a scroll position has been saved.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to do that with your own JS though, as you have to save information regarding an external site. I'll post this as an answer later